# $item->isNominal() will check if an item is Nominal, how do we check if it is not

Tags: quote, recurring, addtocart

If this function `$item->isNominal()` will check if an item is Nominal (recurring) when adding it to the quote(cart), how do we do the opposite and check if an item is Non Recurring (or Normal)?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply check the inverse case. If `if ($item->isNominal())` checks for items that are Nominal then `if (!$item->isNominal())` will check to see if the item is not nominal.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate can be:

```
if(!$item->getProduct()->getIsRecurring()){
       your code.............
     }
```